# select Query Run for hibernateTemplate.save()

Tags: hibernate, spring, orm, jakarta-ee

I am using hibernate 3.5.0 final with spring.In this I want to save data to a table which has a composite key associated from three other tables.I have used hibernateTemplate.save().But when I see the logs it clearly shows that there is a select happening before every insert.I am not able to identify the reason still.

Please help!

**Mapping:**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="class1" table="EVENT_ASSET_DISPOSITION">
        <composite-id name="id" class="Idclass">
            <key-property name="pk1" type="java.math.BigInteger">
                <column name="PK_1" precision="38" scale="0"  not-null="true"/>
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="pk2" type="long">
                <column name="PK_2" not-null="true" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="pk3" type="long">
                <column name="PK_3" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="true"/>
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="column1" type="java.math.BigDecimal" generated="insert">
            <column name="COLUMN_1" precision="38" scale="0" />
        </property> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**SQL:-**

[STDOUT] (pool-14-thread-1) insert into TABLE_1 (COLUMN_1,PK_1,PK_2,PK_3) values (?, ?, ?, ?,)
2011-02-14 08:28:30,312 INFO  [STDOUT] (pool-14-thread-1) Hibernate: select table1_.COLUMN_1 as COLUMN1_280_ from TABLE_1 as table1_ where table1_.PK_1=? and table1_.PK_2=? and table1_.PK_3=?

Cheers,
Dwarak

Comment: Can you show your mappings and the logged SQL statements?

Comment: I have added to the Question.Not enough space in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

One mechanism that hibernate uses to decide if an object is transient or not is versioning

if you add a version column to your mapping/object it should solve the problem

```
<version name="version" column="version" type="integer" unsaved-value="undefined"/>
```

EDIT 1:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-version

@see section 5.1.9

Comment: Should this have a column called version in the Table???I am getting column not found exception.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-version   see section 5.1.9

Comment: is this normal behavior? why would hibernate do a select before save? do we must add versioning all the time in order to avoid it?

Comment: as far as i know; yes, there is no other way for hibernate to distinguish the 2 objects.

Answer (score 0):

The log shows that `select` is issued after `insert`. It's caused by the fact that `column1` is declared as `generated="insert"`, therefore Hibernate need to fetch generated values of that column after `insert`.

**See also:**

- [5.5. Generated properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated)