# Why does Grails issue SELECT statements on instance save()?

Tags: hibernate, grails, optimization, query-optimization

Each time I save() a new domain object in Grails I see Hibernate issuing Select statements for each of the unique constraints in my Grails domain class.

If I save without validation, I don't see the Select statements. Example:

`new Person(name: 'Foo').save(validate: false)`

**Is there a way to stop these extra Select statements from occurring while still having validation enabled?**

One of my goals is to decrease appserver/database chattiness since I am expecting my Grails app to run on a high latency network (e.g., communicating from Grails app => DB can be costly).

Burt has one suggestion, but I'm hoping for something easier/cleaner:

- [Grails save() Domain Object actually does a Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893291/grails-save-domain-object-actually-does-a-select)

This may be a Hibernate issue more than Grails. I'm not sure.

Maybe some other related info:

- [Why does hibernate do the SELECT before SAVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590881/why-does-hibernate-do-the-select-before-save)
- [select Query Run for hibernateTemplate.save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992161/select-query-run-for-hibernatetemplate-save)
- [Force Hibernate Insert Without Select Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588657/force-hibernate-insert-without-select-statements)

Comment: Hopefully, you now see why it does those selects.  Validation is determining if your uniquely constrained field is actually unique, and doesn't use a failure to insert to do so, as that wouldn't allow Grails to respond with WHICH field failed.

Comment: @BillJames right, I began realizing that after I posted. However I was hoping to parse the SQL error message myself (DB constraint name => Grails field maybe, not sure if possible) and re-throw the exception as a Grails ValidationException. Let me know if you can think of a way other than Burt's to stop these Selects. I don't want to resort to monkey patching, but maybe as a last resort. :)

Comment: Well, no, I don't know a way to change the functionality of the unique constraint...  You have to stop using it if you don't want it to do it's job.

Comment: A Grails constraint is supposed to be able to validate the object before inserting or updating it on the DB. For a Unique constraint, the only way to do so is to issue a query to check whether there exists already a conflicting record. You can see the source code for the unique constraint [here](http://is.gd/egyM1g). If that's not what you want, you might want to define your own constraint that does away with the select and/or add client code to deal with the unique key exception arising from the DB. You might want to investigate the options Hibernate provide in this regard.